# Vue/Node tries to serve app to Directory name instead of localhost

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I've been building a Vue app for a while now and have never had an issue running it in development using "npm run serve". Something happened which removed localhost from being the default way to host the dev instance.

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://Kyles-MacBook-Pro.local:8080/ 
  - Network: http://Kyles-MacBook-Pro.local:8080/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

this is different than the usual localhost:8080 and for the network one, "IP":8080

since it is not pointing at localhost it fails

```
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND Kyles-MacBook-Pro.local
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1457:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-test@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test-test@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

based on the research I've done the error "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" would be resolved if i was listening on localhost.

I don't know what could have changed as it was working 2 days ago and I made no changes until trying to run it again to see this Error.

I have un/reinstalled vue, npm, and node. My host file looks like...

```
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

I don't know if something changed in my node files, or maybe vue, but if anyone has an idea on how i can get back to pointing to localhost it would be greatly appreciated.

*Edit*
i do not have a vue.config.js file
this is my package.json

```
  "name": "test-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.2.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

EDIT 2

after making a vue.config.js file and entering this too it

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8080,
    public: 'localhost:8080',
  }
}
```

my output when trying to launch the project is now

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://Kyles-MacBook-Pro.local:8080/ 
  - Network: http://localhost:8080/
```

But it still errors out due to "Local:" being a bad host. I tried to ping it just in case and it indeed cannot be resolved to a ping.
I don't understand how the module.exports file isn't overriding the default host and there has to be another file with higher precedent setting that.

*FINAL EDIT*

It is not the best of solutions, but adding

```
127.0.0.1 Kyles-MacBook-Pro.local
```

to my etc/host file now allows me to run the app locally. 
There is still a bigger issue elsewhere that I need to hunt down that is setting Local away from localhost, but for now this workaround will do.

Comment: Did you use `vue-cli` to create the app? Can you show your `package.json`?

Comment: Also, do you have a file at the root of your project called `vue.config.js`? If so, can you post it's contents?

Comment: @MattOestreich thank you for the response, I have updated the post. This error is happening on all vue projects on my computer, but if a someone pulls the code down from github, it compiles properly and serves to localhost on their machine. Since this is universal across all vue projects on my system i was thinking it is more likely a node issue or Vue setting issue and not necessarily locked into a specific project folder.

Comment: On your machine what happens if you run `ping localhost` from a terminal?

Comment: Successful
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms

Comment: I wonder if you have an environmental variable thats messing with it? Are you familiar with `vue ui` at all? I know you can check the `vue-cli-service serve` command (you can check if a hostname is specified there)..

Comment: I am digging into this now, as well as going through my node_modules folder to see if i can find a config file that allows me to update the host. Will update when i have a workaround or solution

Comment: `.local` reminds of the `dotenv` package, which also uses `.local` as the suffix on local config files.  No idea if there's any correlation.